# Shift columns to the right

Tags: sas

I have a SAS dataset which looks like this:

```
Month  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
200801  11   2    3    20
200802   5   9    4    10
  .      .   .    .     .
  .      .   .    .     .
  .      .   .    .     .
201212   3   34   1     0
```

I want to create a dataset by shift each row's column Col1-Col4 values, to the right. It will look diagonally shifted.

```
Month  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4  Col5 Col6 Col7 . . . . . . . Coln
200801  11   2    3    20
200802   .   5    9     4    10
  .      .   .    .     .
  .      .   .    .     .
  .      .   .    .     .
201212   .   .    .     .    .    .     .  . . 3   34   1   0
```

Can someone suggest how I can do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First off, if you can avoid doing so, do.  This is a pretty sparse way to store data, and will involve large datasets (definitely use OPTIONS COMPRESS at least), and usually can be worked around with good use of CLASS variables.

If you really must do this, `PROC TRANSPOSE` is your friend.  While this is possible in the data step, it's less messy and more flexible in PROC TRANSPOSE.

First, make a totally vertical dataset (month+colname+colvalue):

```
data pre_t;
set have;
array cols col1-col4;
do _t = 1 to dim(cols);
colname = cats("col",((_N_-1) + _t)); *shifting here, edit this logic as needed;
value = cols[_t];
output;
keep colname value month;
run;
```

In that datastep, you are creating the eventual column name in `colname` and setting it up for transpose.  If you have data not identical to the above (in particular, if you have data grouped by something else), *N* may not work and you may need to do some logic (such as figuring out difference from 200801) to calculate the col#.

Then, proc transpose:

```
proc transpose data=pre_t out=want;
by month;
id colname;
var value;
run;
```

And voilà, you should have what you were looking for.  Make sure it's sorted properly in order to get the output in the expected order.